# How to store custom class-level data on models, using Concerns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to make a concern that checks if a user is subscribed to an appropriate plan for my SaaS app.

Here's basically what I'm trying to do:

```
module SubscriptionControlled extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    def requires_subscription_to(perm)
      @@perms = [perm]
    end
  end

  included do
    validate :check_subscription
  end


  def check_subscription
    @@perms.each do |perm|
      self.errors.add(:base, "Subscription upgrade required for access to this feature") unless self.user[perm]
    end
  end


end
```

This provides this api for a model:

```
class SomeModel < ApplicationModel
  include SubscriptionControlled

  requires_subscription_to :pro
end
```

The problem I'm having is that `@@perms` seems to be scoped to the CONCERN, rather than the MODEL. So this value is the same for all models. So whichever model is loaded last sets this value for all models.

eg: if loaded in this order:

```
Model1 -> sets @@perms to [:pro]
Model2 -> sets @@perms to [:business]
```

Both model 1 and model 2 will only require a subscription to :business

Is there a way of storing class-level variables in a concern that take effect on a per-model basis to accomplish this API?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Ruby interpreter at hand right now but I'm fairly certain that using a single `@` in the class method should do the trick. Another thing that comes to mind is something along the lines of

```
included do
  define_singleton_method :requires_subscription_to do |new_perm|
    @@perms ||= []
    @@perms << Array(new_perm)
  end
end
```

Since that will create a new method every time the concern is included, it should work. I just seem to remember that methods defined like that are slightly slower - but since it will probably only be called during initialization, it shouldn't pose a problem in any case.

Comment: So using @perms doesn't work, but I found a way to explicitly make class methods with class-level variable scopes

Answer (score 0):

So I found the right way to do this using a `ClassMethods` module

```
module SubscriptionControlled extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  module ClassMethods
    @perms = []
    def requires_subscription_to(perm)
      @perms = [perm]
    end

    def perms
      @perms
    end
  end

  included do
    validate :check_subscription
  end


  def check_subscription
    self.class.perms.each do |perm|
      self.errors.add(:base, "Subscription upgrade required for access to this feature") unless self.user[perm]
    end
  end


end
```

this keeps the permissions scoped to the class, not the concern.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overcomplicating this. You don't need the `check_subscription` method at all and that method is why you're trying to make `@@perms` (or `@perm`) work.

`validate` is just a class method like any other and you can give `validate` block. You can use that block to capture the `perm` and do away with all the extra machinery:

```
module SubscriptionControlled extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  module ClassMethods
    def requires_subscription_to(perm)
      validate do
        self.errors.add(:base, "Subscription upgrade required for access to this feature") unless self.user[perm]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Oh yes, makes sense. I'll play with that approach, much more concise